# Google Scripts - Test deployment on sheets only works in legacy mode

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Currently I have a standalone google scripts add-on project that I want to share with my colleagues for them to test. When I deploy to test in the new version of google scripts like below image the add on doesn't appear within any Google Sheets.

Shows Test Deployment screen:
[image: Shows Test Deployment screen]

but when I install using the legacy editor it works and shows up under the add-ons menu in a sheet:

Shows Legacy Test Deployment screen:
~[Shows Legacy Test Deployment screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98aTT.png)

Why might that be the case?

**appscript.json**

```
    {
        "timeZone": "Europe/London",
        "dependencies": {},
        "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
        "oauthScopes": [
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly" ,
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"
        ],
        "runtimeVersion": "V8",
        "addOns": {
            "common": {
                "name": "Test app",
                "logoUrl": "https://link/to/logo.png", 
                "layoutProperties": {
                    "primaryColor": "#2772ed"
                },
                "homepageTrigger": {
                    "runFunction": "showSidebar",
                    "enabled": true
                }
           },    
           "sheets": {}
        }
    }
```

**onOpen**

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() 
      .createMenu('Test Project')
      .addItem('Run', 'showSidebar')
      .addToUi();
}
```

This is fine for now, but i have concerns that the legacy editor could just disappear at any point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer:

*The new IDE does not currently support testing add-ons.*

#### More Information:

The [Official Google Documentation for Testing an add-on](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/how-tos/testing-editor-addons#run_a_test_configuration) warns the following:

> Note: You must use the legacy editor to test Editor Add-ons. To switch from the new editor to the legacy editor, click **Use legacy editor** at the top of the editor screen.

I suspect that this is in the works due to the acknowledgement of this missing feature. You can bring this to Google's attention, however, by filing a Feature Request for this on their [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com).